# How can i achieve an EOF by pressing [CTRL]+[D] at scanf()?

Tags: c, eof

(System: Linux Mint 18.1)

How can i achieve an **EOF** by pressing [CTRL]+[D] at `scanf()`?

At the time it only works with [CTRL]+[C], 
however our task is to achieve it by [CTRL]+[D] explicit in `scanf()`.

My function is the following:

```
float getFloat1()
{
  float num = 0.0;
  char term;
  char loop = 'y';

  while (loop == 'y')
  {
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    if (scanf("%f%c", &num, &term) != 2 || term != '\n')
    {
      printf("[ERR] Invalid input.\n");
      while ((getchar()) != '\n');  // Flushes the scanf() input buffer
    }
    else
    {
      printf("[OK]  Valid input: %f\n", num);
      loop = 'n';
    }
  }
  return num;
}
```

I am grateful for any help, links, references and hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to store the result of scanf. Then compare the variable in the block to see if EOF was captured.

```
float getFloat1()
{
    float num = 0.0;
    char term;
    char loop = 'y';
    int result = 0;

    while (loop == 'y')
    {
        printf("Please enter a number: ");
        if ((result = scanf("%f%c", &num, &term)) != 2 || term != '\n')
        {
            if ( result == EOF) {
                printf ( "EOF\n");
                break;
            }
            printf("[ERR] Invalid input.\n");
            while ((getchar()) != '\n');  // Flushes the scanf() input buffer
        }
        else
        {
            printf("[OK]  Valid input: %f\n", num);
            loop = 'n';
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, worked fine for me!
Is there also a way to not only quit the function, but also the whole program by pressing [CTRL]+[D]?

Answer (score 0):

this statement:

```
while ((getchar()) != '\n');
```

would be one place to check for EOF.  Suggest:

```
int ch;
while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF && '\n' != ch );
```

The question was a bit unclear about checking for EOF on the call to `scanf()`